# WooCommerce: How to change the product link conditionally?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In `WooCommerce`, I'm trying to change the default product link format `https://domain-name.com/product/single-product-name/` for sold out products to the following format: `https://domain-name.com/product/single-product-name/#reviews`.

So I need to add `#reviews` to the product link, if the product is sold out.

Via `functions.php`, this removes the regular product link:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
```

**But how can I turn this:**

```
<a href="https://my-domain.com/product/the-product-title/">
```

**into this?**

```
<a href="https://my-domain.com/product/the-product-title/#reviews">
```

The relevant `HTML` structure for each product on the page is:

```
<li class="product">
   <a href="https://my-domain.com/product/the-product-title/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link">
     <img width="300" height="480" src="https://my-domain.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/the-product-title-300x480.jpg">
     <h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">The Product Title</h2>
   </a>
</li
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function append_reviews_to_sold_out_products( $post_link, $post ) {

    // If post is not a product, return default $post_link.
    if ( 'product' != $post->post_type ) {
        return $post_link;
    }
    
    // Get the product from the post ID
    $wcpf = new WC_Product_Factory();  
    $product = $wcpf->get_product($post->ID);

    // Check that it's managing stock, and that it has no stock
    if ( $product->managing_stock() && !$product->is_in_stock() ){
        // Append #reviews
        $post_link .= '#reviews';
    }
    
    // Return the link, appended or not.
    return $post_link;
    
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'append_reviews_to_sold_out_products', 15, 4 );
```